# Overwrite Xamarin default styles

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

By default, Xamarin implements [some styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/styles/):

- BodyStyle
- CaptionStyle
- ListItemDetailTextStyle
- ListItemTextStyle
- SubtitleStyle
- TitleStyle

I know that I can define my own styles, overwrite the default style of a control, etc. However I can't achieve to overwrite the these styles.

Is it possible to overwrite them from the XAML? I am using Xamarin Forms and I would like to change it in the portable project.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, that your request is currently not supported. As you can see from the `Device.Styles` class [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Device+Styles/), the `Styles` are declared as `readonly` which means you will currently not be able to change or override these ones specifically.

This means that you will have to, for now, implement your own interpretation of the built-in `Styles`.